# Could I create ASP.net page method in web form code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Could I declare asp.net page method in side Web form code behind file using [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] attribute?

Comment: PageMethods ARE in code-behind pages, which is why they are called PageMethods!

Comment: Yes, and it will work unless you using FriendlyUrls

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the **code inline** if you want - it's pretty messy though.  Take a look at this [`blog post`](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx) for help.  Also, take a look at this [`MSDN reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290385%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a comparison.  There is also another [`tutorial`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8178/Inline-Single-File-vs-CodeBehind) here.

*In my opinion*, if you need to use webforms, then you should stick to the code behind model and keep the minimum about of code in there for the event handlers only.  Move any **business logic**, or **utility code** into separate classes.